# Migrating from Cassandra 2.2.0 to DSE 4.8.5 (Cassandra 2.1.3)

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have been building an application using Apache Cassandra 2.2.0 for sometime now. We plan to start using the DataStax Enterprise 4.8.5 (this is built on Apache Cassandra 2.1.3).

Problem is as this is a downgrade of Cassandra version, 2.2.0 -> 2.1.3, I am not able to read the SSTables created by Cassandra version 2.2.0.

What can I do to have my old data available with DSE 4.8.5?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. You should consider contacting Datastax for advice (that's one of the advantages of paying for DSE, you get someone to talk to about topics like this).

You'd almost certainly have to export the data and re-import it (either using `sstable2json` or `COPY TO`+`COPY FROM` to export it to a CSV using CQLSH, or using something like Spark or CQLSSTableWriter to recreate 2.1 sstables.